# How to use x:Bind without any property

Tags: c#, binding, winrt-xaml, uwp, xbind

In Windows 8.1, I can do this

```
<Grid Margin="8"
      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
      Tapped="Grid_OnTapped"
      Tag="{Binding}"></Grid>
```

then inside event Grid_OnTapped, I can use the Tag property of Grid to know which item is tapped.

But when change to x:Bind, it's no longer work. Exception throwed: "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object"

Further test, this code will display the name of the class

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}/>
```

But that the only thing work

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code of your constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{x:Bind}` is for binding to properties in the **code-behind** of the view. It has a **performance advantage** over `{Binding}` because normal binding uses reflection to find properties, whereas `x:Bind` does not. `x:Bind` will bind to strongly typed properties in the code-behind.

Generally, you would use `x:Bind` to gain performance in `XAML`.

In your case, it would be a better idea to bind the to `DataContext` instead, in your case, is just `{Binding}`. Which is what you have already done previously.

Perhaps you have misunderstood the usage of `x:Bind`? Here's an [article](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/xbind-xphase-and-xaml-performance-in-windows-10) explaining how it should be used.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood of x:Bind. Thought it was {Binding} replacement. Turn out this is a whole new mechanism.

Comment: Arguably, the far more important improvement of `{x:Bind}` over `{Binding}` is the maintainability aspect. It performs **compile-time** validation, catching bugs as early as possible. Also worth noting: `{x:Bind}` can be used with functions just as well. It is not exclusively for properties (see [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)).